# Material-UI Datagrid Lag and Performance Issues using Autocomplete component with RenderCell

Tags: javascript, reactjs, autocomplete, datagrid, material-ui

I'm using material ui datagrid (https://material-ui.com/components/data-grid/) and I'm adding a Autocomplete component to the cell in multiple columns. (I need about 20 columns in the table)

When I move the table with the scrollbar from left to right the table lags a lot and it's very slow.

This is the custom column that I'm using, I have 20 of these so on my app lags even more

```
{
    field: "lastName",
    headerName: "lastName1",
    disableClickEventBubbling: true,
    width: 200,
    renderCell: (params1) => {
      return (
        <Autocomplete
          options={["1", "2"]}
          defaultValue={params1.getValue("lastName")}
          getOptionLabel={(option) => option}
          style={{ width: "100%", paddingTop: 20 }}
          renderInput={(params) => (
            <TextField
              {...params}
              defaultValue={params1.getValue("lastName")}
            />
          )}
        />
      );
    }
  }
```

Sandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-fqigr

Try to move from left to right and you will see the problem that I'm facing, Lags a lot and I dont think that should be happening.

Comment: Hi. You seem to have removed most of the info from your post by accident and I have undone that. If you are editing to improve please see [ask] for guidance.